# What's the formal name of single cell in a parking lot?

Tags: terminology

What can I call the single cell/space in a parking lot? I mean a single square area for a single vehicle.

```
A parking lot
---------------------------------
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
| 1A| 1B|   |   |   |   |   |   | << What do we call these single cells?
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
---------------------------------

---------------------------------
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
---------------------------------
```

Comment: It depends on the country. The answer by _Jason Bassford_ references a US dictionary, and _Greendrake_ gives you the term often used in British English.

Comment: This question has been asked before.

Comment: Unfortunately, those who were active users at the time and submitted answers or cast their votes have mostly gone.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are [**parking places/spaces/spots**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/parking%20space):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> a place to park a car, truck, etc.

(In other words, **parking places**, **parking spaces**, or **parking spots**.)

According to [Google Books Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=parking%20space%2Cparking%20place%2Cparking%20spot&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cparking%20space%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cparking%20place%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cparking%20spot%3B%2Cc0), The most common of the three terms seems to be **parking space**.

Answer (score 3):

They're often called parking **bay**s.
In New Zealand, I also heard them called just **park**s.

Comment: +1 for introducing me to a new regional term. I should note, however, that Oxford defines [**parking bay**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/parking_bay) as "A recess at the side of a road for parking a vehicle." That doesn't actually match the spots available in lots. (But perhaps it's used for those anyway.)

Comment: (I am familiar with **parking bays** here in Canada, but the term is not used to refer to residential parking. Instead it refers to places in garages where cars are repaired or serviced, or to industrial sites where large delivery trucks pick up or deliver goods.)

Answer (score 0):

In England it is called a "Parking Bay"